# How to set responsive navigation bar that dropdown over the site content?

Tags: html, css, navigation, responsive

I created a navigation bar.
When I open it on mobile I want it to open with a transparent background above the content of the site and not push the content of the site down, how is that possible using html, css and js ( without bootstrap)?

Answer (score 0):

```css
    body{
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      }
    #navbar {
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 1;
      background-color: black;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
      #navbar{
        background-color: transparent;
      } 
    }
```

```html
  <nav id="navbar">
    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
    <h3 style="color: orange;">My site</h3>
    <h5 style="color: white;">Some link</h5>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <h1>Hello world!</h1>
```

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks for the help! I tried it but it does not work. It just disapre my navbar and also I change the opacity to 0.4 for exemple, it just creates a transparent menu and still push the rest of the site's content down. I want the drop-down menu to be transparent and be on over the content of the site, do you have another idea ?

Comment: Check my answer again. I edited that. Added the whole code needed. If you want explanation, please comment down here.